# How to calculate the Lebesgue measure of the set $\big\{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2:xy\leq 1/2\big\}$?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Define $B:=\big\{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2:xy\leq 1/2\big\}$.

Let $\lambda ^2$ be the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$. How can I calculate $\lambda ^2(B)$?

I tried to obtain that value calculating the Lebesgue integral of the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_B$, but I couldn't find a nice way to express this function in order to calculate the integral.

Please help me!

Comment: Maybe try to plot the area of $B$ on a diagram? Visualisation helps

Comment: It's just the area under the graph of $y(x) = 1/(2x)$ and inside of $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: @Surge I know, but I'd like to know how to obtain that value without visualizing a graph.

Comment: @noob Use Fubini's Theorem in order to compute the integral.

Comment: Can you express the area using Riemann integration? As in write it as a nested integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $B:=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2:xy\leq1/2\}$. From Fubini's Theorem,
$$
\text{Area of B} = \int_{[0,1]^2}1_B dxdy = \int_0^1\left(\int_0^{\min\{1,\frac1{2x}\}}1 dy \right)dx.
$$
So the area of $B$ is given by
$$
\int_0^1 \min\left\{1,\frac{1}{2x}\right\} dx.
$$
In other words, the area in the square, below the curve given by $\dfrac1{2x}$. The $\min\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ makes sure you do not go above the top side of the square. Hence, the area is
$$
\int_0^{1/2} 1 dx + \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{1}{2x} dx = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left[ \ln x\right]_{1/2}^1 = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + 0 - \ln \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \right)= \frac{1}{2}(1 + \ln 2).
$$

Update: Thanks to @Mark below who spotted my error. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I just realized that if $B:=\big\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x\in A\wedge g_1(x)\leq y\leq g_2(x)\big\}$ with $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $g_1$, and $g_2$ Borel mensurable, then $\int _Dfd\lambda ^2=\int _{A}\int _{[g_1(x),g_2(x)]}f(x,y)d\lambda (y)d\lambda (x)$ for all function Lebesgue integrable $f$.